# Android Eclipse HorizontalScrollView Fling / Swipe help

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a few customised Views in my Android app. I want to add these to a HorizontalScrollView and be able to fling / swipe through them.

Could someone help me please on this at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code.  You must implement OnGestureListener and OnClickListener:

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() //
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) //
        {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) //
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) //
{
    int changeInX = (int) (e2.getX() - e1.getX());

    // If the swipe was big enough, do something
    if (Math.abs(changeInX) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY) //
    {
        if (velocityX > 0) //
            activity.animateSwipe(true);
        else
            activity.animateSwipe(false);

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

    public void animateSwipe(boolean right) {
    TranslateAnimation anim = null;

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) this
            .findViewById(R.id.layoutVolume);

    if (right) {
        anim = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, layout.getWidth(), 0.0f, 0.0f);
    } else {
        anim = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, -layout.getWidth(), 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    anim.setDuration(250);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));

    layout.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Comment: Does this go in my main class where the HorizontalScrollView is?

Comment: Also I am not sure what this represents? activity.animateSwipe(true);

Comment: This goes in your main activity, typically.  I use MVC architecture to keep my UI seperate from the controller, but that is your choice.  I added the additional code.

Comment: Any working example at all? I am not sure how to implement this to be honest! I have already added a HorizontalScrollView into my main activity then some other views into the HorizontalScrollView , now just want to fling through those added views.

Comment: This is a working example, you just have to try and implement it in your code.  The layoutVolume is the layout that you want to fling.  This is for a horizontal fling, but the principles should be the same, just switch the x and y axis.

Comment: Got it working. In terms of being able to catching the onFling. Now when I have to Views side by side in the HorizontalScrollView, when I "fling" it, it tries to go to the next View but then goes back to the first one!

Comment: Make sure that you're properly switching the views, and not just animating them.  It sounds like you're using the animation code, but not updating the UI.

Comment: I make sure I fade out the one that need leaving and fade in the one that needs entering. But how does one update the UI? Sorry to be a pain!

Comment: You have to actually change the view in the UI in code... HorizontalScrollView.addView(newView) or something similar

Comment: Two important points I'll make to you as a new user :) - accept and/or upvote answers when they answer your question, please.  Also, keep in mind this is a site for specific questions and answers, not a "please write my app/class/method for me" site.  You are expected to be able to do your own research in the documentation and using Google, as well as the resources people provide here.